# Nest array of functions that return promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Here I have 4 functions that return promises. If you run hello and pass each on into the next `.then` you get one long string.

```
var hello = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "hello")
}
var world = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "world")
}
var foo = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "foo")
}
var bar = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "bar")
}

// hello("alpha").then(world).then(foo).then(bar).then(console.log)
// => alphahelloworldfoobar
```

I'd like to be able to pass a flat array of the functions into a function and get return a function that has them all nested.

```
var arr = wrapThen([
  hello,
  world,
  foo,
  bar
])

arr("alpha").then(console.log)
```

Is this possible? Does bluebird offer this?

This is what I hacked together:

```
function wrapThen(arr){
  var headPromise = arr.shift()
  return function(){
    var args = _.values(arguments)
    var init = headPromise(args)
    var values = []
    return Promise.each(arr, function(item){
      init = init.then(item)
      return init.then(function(value){
        values.push(value)
        return value
      })
    }).then(function(){
      return _.last(values)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is pretty easy with bluebird, with a `reduce`, this is fundamentally what a `reduce` does anyway (aggregate result):

```
let result = Promise.reduce([hello, world, foo, bar], function(result, action){
    return action(result);
}, "alpha");
```

In ES2015 notation this becomes even less verbose:

```
let {reduce} = Promise;
let result = reduce(arr, (result, action) => action(result), "alpha");
```

```js
var hello = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "hello");
};
var world = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "world");
};
var foo = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "foo");
};
var bar = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "bar");
};


Promise.reduce([hello, world, foo, bar], function(result, action){
    return action(result);
}, "alpha").then(function(endResult){ 
    console.log(endResult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.33/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want all function to get same param `alpha` or still pass as sequence, so I write both, just use `.reduce` and `.map` you can achieve both way.

```js
var hello = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "hello");
};
var world = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "world");
};
var foo = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "foo");
};
var bar = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "bar");
};
 
// Wrap all functions in list, all give them the same value.
var wrapToArray = function(list) {
  
  return function(result) {
    var allP = list.map(function(item) {
      return item(result);
    });
    return Promise.all(allP);
  };
  
};

// Wraps all, and resolve them by array's sequence.
var wrapToSequence = function(list) {
  
   return  function(result) {
    // Create a promise that resolved with result first.
    var promise = Promise.resolve(result);
    // Use reduce to chain the functions.
    promise = list.reduce(function(prev, item) {
      return prev.then(item);
    }, promise);
    return promise;
  };

};

var arr = wrapToArray([hello, world, foo, bar]);
var arr2 = wrapToSequence([hello, world, foo, bar]);

arr("alpha").then(console.log.bind(console));
arr2("alpha").then(console.log.bind(console));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/2.9.33/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Bluebird also provide [.reduce](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#reducefunction-reducer--dynamic-initialvalue---promise), [.map](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise) to create it easier, to avoid the answer become longer, demo is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7q0k7a8/).

```
var wrapToSequence = function(list) {
   return  function(result) {
    return  Promise.reduce(list, function(result, fn) {
      return fn(result);
    }, result);
  };
};

var wrapToArray = function(list) {
  return function(result) {
    return Promise.map(list, function(fn) {
      return fn(result);
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do this using [`Ramda`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeP).

```
var R = require("ramda")

var hello = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "hello")
}
var world = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "world")
}
var foo = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "foo")
}
var bar = function(str){
  return Promise.resolve(str+ "bar")
}

var result = R.pipeP(hello, world, foo, bar)

result("alpha").then(console.log) // logs -> "alphahelloworldfoobar"

result("alpha") // promise -> "alphahelloworldfoobar"
```